# Pusher Receive Data Null

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pusher

I am using laravel 5.8 version. I'm sending message and user value to pusher but put pusher receive event 
{"message": null, "user": null}.
Here is my broadcasting.php file

```
 'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
//                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
//                'useTLS' => true,
                'cluster' => 'ap2',
                'useTLS' => true
            ],
        ],
```

Here is my chatevent.php file.
namespace App\Events;

```
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class ChatEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $message;
    public $user;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message, User $user)
    {
        $this->$message = $message;
         $this->$user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

And there is my bootstrap.js file.

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    // broadcaster: 'pusher',
    // key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    // cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    // encrypted: truebroadcaster: 'pusher',
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
        key:'7d64c4828272fba9bbdd',
        cluster: 'ap2',
        encrypted: true
});
```

My controller function where I'm sending message and user to pusher.

```
 public function send()
    {
        $message = 'hello';
        $user = User::find(Auth::id());

        event(new ChatEvent($message, $user));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add payload inside your chatEvent class: and also you are accessing data members in wrong way write:

```
 $this->message = $message; //right way
```

instead of:

```
$this->$message = $message; //wrong way,(remove dollar sign when using $this->)
```

write code as follows: you can replace message variable with payload also:

```
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class ChatEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $message;
    public $user;
    public $payload;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message, User $user, $payload)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
         $this->user = $user;
         $this->payload = $payload;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```